# JS XLSX npm module - write data to existing xlsx

Tags: javascript

I am looking to overwrite a cell value of a data column in an existing worksheet.
Is there a way I can do this using XLSX npm module?

Comment: Which XLSX npm module are you referring to?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx